# Can't open my mac after installing windows using bootcamp

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, error

My macbook pro isn't working well after I installed windows 8.1 using bootcamp. It displays the blue screen, and get an error. Now there is only Windows option in startup, and it says that your PC need to repair.

I can't open either Windows, or Mac, and the big thing is there's no mac option on startup.

Comment: Have you tried holding the Alt/Option key on startup? Does it show 2 disks (OS X and Bootcamp)? If yes, use arrow keys and navigate. Also, does the chime play? If it does, try holding Alt+Command+P+R until the chime plays 2 times to reset NVRAM

Comment: Yes i did, holding alt/option key shows nothing only windows option on startup, alt+cmd+p+r also did nothing same recovery windows appears

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. But please put this in the comments, not in the answers (as answers are for answers). If you are below 50 rep, you can still comment on your own posts. Try Alt+CMD+P+R on boot. And, does the chime play?

Answer (score 1):

Boot to recovery mode and then choose the Mac startup disk might be the fastest way to determine if the Mac is still bootable.

Apple documents this and the other ways to switch back and forth at:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417

If you've meticulously done all the steps, you might ask a second follow on question with more details about what the situation is.